# CSS - Scaling positioned elements rel. to browser window size

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, position, scaling

Is there a way to make `position`'ed elements scale correctly relative to the window size using only CSS or I got to step it up to javascript/jQ? I tried adding a container with `100%` `width` and `height` and then scale accordingly.

```
.container{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;}

.transblock{
    position:absolute; 
    width:44%; 
    height:5%; 
    top:90%; 
    left:0%; 
    background:green;
    opacity: 0.6;
    z-index:5; }

.h1text{
    position:absolute; 
    width:30%; 
    height:5%;
    top:90.75%; 
    left:13.5%; 
    z-index:10;
    color:white;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cyaXL/

The gap between the paragraph and the menu is the issue. It's too small on 1280p screen and too large on 1920p. Is there any way to make it adjust better?

Comment: (offtopic) `&amp` ~= `&amp;`, `<h2>` ~= `</h2>`

Comment: Sorry but what exactly is the problem you have in the fiddle?

Comment: demos shouldn't take a lot of guessing to see what issue is. Neither should question explanation.   .... Fix what?

Comment: Well the space between the menu and paragraphs for example doesn't really scale well. On a 1280x1024 screen the gap is nonexistent and on 1920p it's a bit too wide. Any ideas how to make it adjust a little better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the fact that you have the .menu4 with a left of 25% is the problem here:

```
.menu4 {
  left: 25%;
}
```

better:

```
.menu4 {
  left: 0%;
  width:auto;
  margin-right:1%;
}

.menu4 ul {
  float:right;
  clear:both;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! good find, works well. I'll play around a little and see if I get everything in order.

Answer (score 10):

You can as well us 'viewport' units like this:

```js
div {
 width: 50vw; //means it should take 50% of the window size
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This must be done through css and not with any scripts and Yes your are doing it right, making the container go 100% of windows size then placing items in that container.

Comment: Must be done? I don't think it MUST be done with CSS necessarily.

Answer (score 0):

You are using font size in pixel. Please try with "em". while doing the layout with %, we need to used "em" instead of "px". please refer the conversion table and try.